# execute aws lambda function sequentially

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, locking, aws-lambda

I have written a python script for autoscaling server naming. which will check current servers in autoscaling and give an appropriate name and sequence to the new server.

I am triggering my Aws lambda function by autoscaling event. and when I bring 3 servers at the same time(or new autoscaling with desired capacity 10) I don't want lambda to be executed parallelly. it is making my script assign the same count for all servers.

Or if I can implement some kind of locking to put other lambdas in wait state. So what should i used for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 options:

1. You can create a distributed lock using a DynamoDB table. This will
   help you maintain a state saying Operation in progress. Every time a
   lambda function is invoked due to an autoscaling event, you can
   check if this record exists in dynamodb. If it does not create one,
   and proceed. If it exists, do nothing and return. After your lambda
   function executes successfully, remove this entry. This probably
   will add not more than $2.00 to your total AWS bill as the read and
   write capacity for this table will be really low.
2. You can make use of the step functions to implement this scenario.
   With step functions you can check if one is already running and
   skip.

   Read more about step functions here:
   https://aws.amazon.com/step-functions/

Comment: My problem is not the orchestration of lambda function but rather multiple instances of the same lambda function are getting executed.
so even if  I use aws step function then multiple instances of aws step function are going to execute.